# In the EU, can I start an R&D company and apply for research grants?

Tags: funding, industry, eu

I am from an EU country and hold a PhD degree in structural mechanics. I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to start a company dedicated to R&D only and apply for research grants for my own projects and ideas? I would be the one hiring research staff and I would be supervising their work.
2. Does anyone know any funding organization, body or foundation that is able to fund privately-held companies?

Comment: In the US, this is quite possible via [SBIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Business_Innovation_Research) and related programs.  I don't know if EU countries have an equivalent, however.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't about academia, so off-topic.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. The outcomes of my research would all be industrial products. Of course, publications can be part of the projects, but they are not a priority. My field is Structural Mechanics (branch of Mechanical Engineering)

Comment: @Buffy Grant-funded R&D work at a company certainly falls within the greater scope of this site: "... anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent fields."

Comment: @jakebeal. The pharma industry does that. Are they in scope?

Comment: @Buffy I'd say that if you're talking about the research, grant-writing, and publications aspects, absolutely --- there's a massive commonality between industry and university activities there.  If you're talking about the manufacture, distribution, and marketing aspects, then no.  But academia involves much besides universities, and this site has long recognized that fact (see, for example: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/expand-scope-of-site-to-include-academics-searching-for-info-on-industry-jobs)

Comment: If your priority is to deliver industrial products, not papers, there are specific grants to do so (sorry, not familiar with the specific EU schemes). However, in most countries grants themselves are not enough to cover salary, office etc.

Comment: You can start an R&D-only company in many countries (including EU countries), but, such a company will surely be doomed, since there's no revenue.

Comment: Doomed unless it builds a portfolio of patents that becomes quite valuable.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Then it isn't R&D-only. Admittedly the term isn't defined, but I took it to mean _not commercialising outputs_.

Answer (score 4):

A significant part of the EU's research framework program (current Horizon 2020) funding is for industrial and technology research, so companies (or consortia which also contain companies) are eligible for funding.  However, the idea here would be to ultimately aim for developing a product - thus, a *pure* R&D company like what you mention might not be the right target.  (Of course, you can always aim for having a company whose product is intellectual property.)

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please send me the link to the documents of the EU research framework program that you are referring to? I would like to read it. Your reply was very helpful. thank you once again!

Comment: https://ec.europa.eu/programmes/horizon2020/en

Comment: Note that "am I eligible to apply for a grant" and "am I likely to be awarded a grant" are two very different questions. A newly-formed company with no track record of success seems unlikely to be competitive for funding.

Comment: @avid Sure, but this was not a question, and should not come as a suprise.

Comment: @user151413 If your answer can't be applied, surely it doesn't meaningfully answer the question? (That said, my answer focused on practicalities and was deleted by a mod.)

Comment: @user2768 There was no mention of "how high are the chances if it is a newly founded company" in the question.  --  Moreover, it is not uncommon that newly founded start-ups are part of EU project consortia, so there is no reason why a newly founded company should have no chances if they have competent staff and a strong proposal.

Comment: @user2768 Also, answers on SE should be *generally applicable* answers which are helpful to others, and not restricted to solely apply to the specific case of the OP.

Comment: When asking a question there's a general expectation that answers are applicable. @user151413 You've asserted yours is unlikely to be applicable, seemingly falling into the category of not being a useful answer. Perhaps you can edit to clarify when your answer is relevant?

Comment: @user2768 I think it *is* relevant. As stated above, if you have a start-up with a convincing concept, I don't see why the EU FP wouldn't fund you.  On the contrary, the point of this funding is precisely to fund research which is not funded otherwise (as it could done e.g. in a big, established company).

Comment: -1 @user151413 In response to, "A newly-formed company with no track record of success seems unlikely to be competitive for funding," you acknowledged, "Sure, but this was not a question, and should not come as a suprise." Your above comment seemingly contradicts that and doesn't offer guidance, so a -1 from me: Your answer doesn't seem applicable.

Comment: @user2768 Are you upset because your answer got deleted?

Comment: @user151413 Those that downvote out of spite should disconnect from the Internet; I downvoted because your answer is not useful: You yourself acknowledged it cannot help the OP. (I see no value in commenting further.)

Comment: @user2768 I didn't acknowledge that. This is only your reading.